# How to avoid duplicate outputs using logging module

Tags: python, logging

I am using the logging module to output what used to be print statements in my script to both the console and a log file. However, each time I run the script, the output seems to append to what was printed in the console and the log, rather than overwrite what was there. For example, the first time I run the script I get this output in my console and log file:

```
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
```

The second time I run the script, I get this in the console:

```
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
The year is: 2015
```

The third time:

```
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
The year is: 2015
The year is: 2015
```

etc.. and the log file keeps appending so that I end up with:

```
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
The year is: 2015
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
The year is: 2015
The year is: 2015
```

What I want is for both the log file and the console to only give me the following, no matter how many times I rerun the script:

```
This print statement is going to both the console and the log
The year is: 2015
```

Note: the only way I can currently get what I want is to shut down Python in between runs of the script, but that is not a practical solution.

I have experimented with using flush() and have tried doing something like this:

```
logger = logging.basicConfig(filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

but I have not been able to get it to work with my code. Can someone please help? Here is my code:

```
import inspect
import logging
import datetime

def getDate():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    m = now.month
    d = now.day
    y = str(now.year)
    if m < 10:
        m = "0"+str(m)
    else:
        m = str(m)
    if d < 10:
        d = "0"+str(d)
    else:
        d = str(d)
    y = y[2:]
    formatted_date = m+d+y
    return formatted_date

def function_logger(file_level, console_level = None):
    function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(function_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #By default, logs all messages

    if console_level != None:
        ch = logging.StreamHandler() #StreamHandler logs to console
        ch.setLevel(console_level)
        ch_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(ch_format)
        logger.addHandler(ch)

    log_name = 'Test_log' + getDate() + '.log'
    fh = logging.FileHandler(log_name.format(function_name))
    fh.setLevel(file_level)
    fh_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(fh_format)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger

def f1():
    global logger
    year = '2015'
    logger.info("The year is: %s" % (year))

def main():

    global logger
    logger = function_logger(logging.INFO, logging.INFO)
    logger.info('This print statement is going to both the console and the log')
    f1()
    logging.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're seeing this because every handler will emit a record once, and if you run your script multiple times, you will register a new handler with every `addHandler()` call. Either keep track of your logging handlers and remove them again in a `try..finally`, or check if there already is one registered for the type you're about to add before adding them.

Comment: (Print `logger.handlers` during each run to see what's going on)

Comment: Thank you. Placing both of my addHandlers under if not logger.handlers:
solved the problem of the duplicate entries. However, there is a secondary problem relating only to the log file in that the log is still appended to instead of overwritten. How can I solve this remaining log problem?

Comment: If you look at [`FileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler)'s constructor, it's `mode` defaults to `'a'` (append). So use `FileHandler(log_name.format(function_name), mode='w')` to overwrite the existing file instead of appending (semantics for `mode` are the same as with [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Lucas Graf, here is how I fixed the code to do exactly what I wanted:

```
def function_logger(file_level, console_level = None):
    function_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
    logger = logging.getLogger(function_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) #By default, logs all messages
    log_name = 'Test_log_' + getDate() + '.log'

    if not logger.handlers:
        if console_level != None:
            ch = logging.StreamHandler() #StreamHandler logs to console
            ch.setLevel(console_level)
            ch_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
            ch.setFormatter(ch_format)
            logger.addHandler(ch)

        fh = logging.FileHandler(log_name.format(function_name), mode='w')
        fh.setLevel(file_level)
        fh_format = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        fh.setFormatter(fh_format)
        logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger
```

There are three things to note about this fix:

1: I moved both addHandlers under the test condition:

```
if not logger.handlers:
```

2: I added mode='w' to the Filhandler:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler(log_name.format(function_name), mode='w')
```

3: I cleared the handlers at the bottom of main():

```
logger.handlers = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do that:

```
def LOG_insere(file, format, text, level):
    infoLog = logging.FileHandler(file)
    infoLog.setFormatter(format)
    logger = logging.getLogger(file)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    
    if not logger.handlers:
        logger.addHandler(infoLog)
        if (level == logging.INFO):
            logger.info(text)
        if (level == logging.ERROR):
            logger.error(text)
        if (level == logging.WARNING):
            logger.warning(text)
    
    infoLog.close()
    logger.removeHandler(infoLog)
    
    return
```