# Suppress multiple messages with same content in Python logging module AKA log compression

Tags: python, logging, error-logging

By design, my application sometimes produces repeating errors which fill up the log file and make it annoying to read. It looks like that:

```
WARNING:__main__:CRON10: clock unset or no wind update received in 60 sec -> supressed rrd update
WARNING:__main__:CRON10: clock unset or no wind update received in 60 sec -> supressed rrd update
WARNING:__main__:CRON10: clock unset or no wind update received in 60 sec -> supressed rrd update
WARNING:__main__:CRON10: clock unset or no wind update received in 60 sec -> supressed rrd update
```

How can I use the Python logging module to suppress repeating messages and output something more rsyslog style (http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html):

```
WARNING:__main__:CRON10: clock unset or no wind update received in 60 sec -> supressed rrd update
--- The last message repeated 3 times
```

Is there a way to extend logging or do I have to write a completly own logger?

The code I use for logging is:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.info)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(LOGFILE)
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid duplicate outputs using logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351287/how-to-avoid-duplicate-outputs-using-logging-module)

Comment: @Anthon: The linked dupe is about the results of registering multiple handlers. That's not the problem described here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can create a [`logging.Filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Filter) that will keep track of the last logged record and filter out any repeated (similar) records, something like:

```
import logging

class DuplicateFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        # add other fields if you need more granular comparison, depends on your app
        current_log = (record.module, record.levelno, record.msg)
        if current_log != getattr(self, "last_log", None):
            self.last_log = current_log
            return True
        return False
```

Then just add it to the logger/handler you use (i.e. `hdlr.addFilter(DuplicateFilter())`) or the root logger to filter all default logs. Here's a simple test:

```
import logging

logging.warn("my test")
logging.warn("my repeated test")
logging.warn("my repeated test")
logging.warn("my repeated test")
logging.warn("my other test")

logger = logging.getLogger()  # get the root logger
logger.addFilter(DuplicateFilter())  # add the filter to it

logging.warn("my test")
logging.warn("my repeated test")
logging.warn("my repeated test")
logging.warn("my repeated test")
logging.warn("my other test")
```

This will print out:

```
WARNING:root:my test
WARNING:root:my repeated test
WARNING:root:my repeated test
WARNING:root:my repeated test
WARNING:root:my other test
WARNING:root:my test
WARNING:root:my repeated test
WARNING:root:my other test
```

Comment: CAVEAT: if `logging.*()` is used with format string arguments (e.g. `logging.warn("some error: %s",errstr)`) the DuplicateFilter will treat any such line as duplicate, as the format string is checked - not the printed string.

Comment: This can be circumvented by calling [`record.getMessage()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord.getMessage)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to overwrite the logging.Logger class in order to modify the _log function:

```
import logging
import zlib


class FilteredLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, name, level=logging.NOTSET):
        super().__init__(name, level)
        self._message_lockup = {}

    def _log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False, log_intervall=None):
        if log_intervall is None or log_intervall == 1:
            super(FilteredLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info)
        else:
            message_Id = zlib.crc32(msg.encode('utf-8'))
            if message_Id not in self._message_lockup:
                self._message_lockup[message_Id] = 0
                super(FilteredLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info)
            elif self._message_lockup[message_Id] % log_intervall == 0:
                msg += f' -- Suppressed {log_intervall} equal messages'
                super(FilteredLogger, self)._log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info)
            self._message_lockup[message_Id] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.setLoggerClass(FilteredLogger)
    logger = logging.getLogger('test_logger')
    consol_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(consol_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    for count in range(1000):
        logger.info('Test log', log_intervall=100)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Test log
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
Test log -- Suppressed 100 equal messages
```

This implementation can easily be customized.