How to suppress or summarize non-consecutive *duplicate* log messages from a Python library function called in a loop?
I'm using a Python library that logs messages using the standard logging module. The library code includes the following at the top of its modules:
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

In my own script, I also set up logging in the same way:
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

I'm calling a library function in a loop. The function is part of a class and looks something like this:
class MathOperations:
    @classmethod
    def square_number(cls, n):
        logger.info("You want to square a number.")
        logger.warning("Squaring Number")
        result = n * n
        logger.info(f"Result: {result}")
        return result

When I run this method in a loop in my script:
for i in range(5):
    MathOperations.square_number(i)

I get a lot of log messages that are essentially duplicates in terms of their content. This makes the logs verbose and hard to read.
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:27] INFO [library.module_name:9] You want to square a number.
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:27] WARNING [library.module_name:10] Squaring Number
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:27] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 0
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:28] INFO [library.module_name:9] You want to square a number.
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:28] WARNING [library.module_name:10] Squaring Number
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:28] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 1
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:29] INFO [library.module_name:9] You want to square a number.
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:29] WARNING [library.module_name:10] Squaring Number
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:29] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 4
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:30] INFO [library.module_name:9] You want to square a number.
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:30] WARNING [library.module_name:10] Squaring Number
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:30] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 9
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:31] INFO [library.module_name:9] You want to square a number.
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:31] WARNING [library.module_name:10] Squaring Number
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:31] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 16

The messages "You want to square a number." and "Squaring Number" are duplicates every time the function is called in the loop.
Desired Log Output:
I would like the logs to be summarized to reduce the number of duplicate messages. Ideally, the output would look something like:
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:27] INFO [library.module_name:9] You want to square a number.
-- The above message repeated 4 more times --
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:27] WARNING [library.module_name:10] Squaring Number
-- The above message repeated 4 more times --
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:27] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 0
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:28] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 1
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:29] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 4
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:30] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 9
[29/Nov/2024 12:32:31] INFO [library.module_name:12] Result: 16

This way, the logs are less cluttered, and I can still see the important information without the repetitive messages.
Constraints:
I cannot modify the library code.
I want to suppress or summarize duplicate log messages only from the library when called in a loop.
I prefer to keep any additional code in my script to a minimum.
What I've tried:
I attempted to create a custom logging.Filter to suppress duplicate messages:
import logging

class SuppressDuplicatesFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.logged_messages = set()

    def filter(self, record):
        message = record.getMessage()
        if message in self.logged_messages:
            return False  # Suppress
        else:
            self.logged_messages.add(message)
            return True  # Allow


def enable_duplicate_suppression():
    library_logger = logging.getLogger('library.module_name')
    suppress_filter = SuppressDuplicatesFilter()
    library_logger.addFilter(suppress_filter)
    # Store for later removal
    enable_duplicate_suppression.filter = suppress_filter


def disable_duplicate_suppression():
    library_logger = logging.getLogger('library.module_name')
    suppress_filter = enable_duplicate_suppression.filter
    library_logger.removeFilter(suppress_filter)
    del enable_duplicate_suppression.filter



enable_duplicate_suppression()


for i in range(5):
    MathOperations.square_number(i)


disable_duplicate_suppression()

However, this doesn't seem to work—the duplicate log messages are still appearing in the logs.
I also tried enhancing the filter to count duplicates and log a summary:
class SummarizingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.last_message = None
        self.repeat_count = 0

    def filter(self, record):
        message = record.getMessage()
        if message == self.last_message:
            self.repeat_count += 1
            return False  # Suppress
        else:
            if self.repeat_count > 0:
                # Log a summary of the repeated message
                summary = f'"{self.last_message}" repeated {self.repeat_count} times'
                #? How to log this appropriately?
            self.last_message = message
            self.repeat_count = 0
            return True  # Allow

But I'm not sure what approach I've missed to get this working, and how to properly log the summary message so that it appears in the logs with the correct formatting and logger name.
How can I effectively suppress or summarize duplicate log messages, even if they are non consecutive, from the library function when called in a loop without modifying the library code? Perhaps by customizing the logging module?
Additional Info:
The library's logger names are based on their module paths (e.g., 'library.module_name').
I'm open to applying the filter to the root logger if necessary, as long as it doesn't interfere with other logging.
I need a solution that works with the standard logging module since I cannot change the library's logging setup.
After the duplicate suppression is activated, it may be that every new unique log gets let through, but then if it's been seen before it is not allowed, and just stored. Then when the duplicate suppression is disabled, the duplicates are released (in a summarised single line each).
Similar SO Question:
Suppress multiple messages with same content in Python logging module AKA log compression
I've taken a look a the above, but I don't think it covers what I'm looking for: it would only suppress logs that are immediately, consecutively duplicate. While I'd like to suppress and summarise even if the same warning is logged non-consecutively.
Thank you for your help!

What are the rules for when the duplicated line should be shown again? Or for when the "repeated N times" message should be shown?

When the duplicate suppression is disabled again. It may be that no logs are printed while this is active, and then all at once when disabled. Alternatively print the first instance of every log but only when it is a duplicate don't print it again. Then when disabled the duplicates are released.
I've extended the question to clarify this point, thank you mkrieger1

To get that result, you'd have to buffer the output for some time, which introduces its own set of problems. Adding some simple filter which remembers the last couple of messages and suppresses repeated messages isn't all that difficult; adding the "repeated x times" is.

Indeed deceze I was expecting all the related SO questions I found to implement this but they all just drop duplicates instead of summarising them which means the information is lost. What are the set of problems you mention using a buffer would cause?

First of all, not sure where exactly you'd hook into the logging system to produce that. Filtering is easy, manipulating the writing system… dunno. But let's say you work that out, you'll need to decide when to start outputting the logs. You can only output a conclusive "repeats x times" when you know there won't be any more coming. When is that? And until then, you can't output anything. You'll need to decide on some thresholds, like 1 second buffer at most. But then slower processes can still produce duplicate lines. Also the order of messages is changed, maybe complicating debugging.

Indeed a few things to think about. I'll defer to your expertise of course, a naïve way could be: when enabled, redirect all logs from the specifically requested library to write to a temporary file (or some kind of buffer). Then when disabled, the contents of the file are modified: 1. count & store duplicates 2. print the non-duplicates in order 3. print the summarised version of the duplicates, in order of first appearance. 4. delete the temp file.
Your question on the hooking / blocking the logs, is the part I find myself without enough knowledge to progress just yet!

The problem with the "repeated X times" is that you have to write it immediately, but it has to refer to lines that won't be written for ... days, maybe. This might be better as an analysis tool for an already-written log file.

I do have a similar tool for an email alerts tool. You can know how many times the message will repeat if it's part of a daily report.

I will delete my answer :-p but I think what you are trying to achieve is expensive in terms of performance. Linux kernel does a similar thing and just logs the number of repeated messages but it was designed to do that.

Indeed, no need to make this dynamically summarise repeats. Just capture logs when turned on, and generate the summarised version when turned off. I plan to use it around a very verbose library call!

@SWA if you wanted this for a very verbose library,then you can consider nonpython console tools,etc. like a feature packed console, what you have asked doesn't require some innovative work, but just algorithm code which is hard to build by us for you from scratch.

Great suggestion redoc. Any ideas?

you yourself are calling the log lines in loop and then trying to figure out a way to print them only once. If you want this only once then why can't you just call the below two log lines before performing the mathematical operation (i.e actually calling the function)
logger.info("You want to square a number.")
logger.warning("Squaring Number")

Ah, @Harpreet, because sadly the code that is doing the logging is in a library, not within my script. I call classes & methods imported from that library in a loop, hence the question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/44691558/2834978

When the complexity of the desired adapter outweighs the complexity of the library, its very hard to justify the effort for that solution. e.g. you could just as easily suppress logging while the function is looped, and then have the invoker post a summary of the invocations. Each use-case is likely to be different, and trying to solve this for the general case over all methods is an effort in madness. The logger library is a hammer, but not everything is a nail.

What I get from your question is that your main goal is to analyze an uncluttered view of your log messages. Why not take a pragmatic approach: forget about filtering and write a short script that postprocesses your logs by parsing the log files and providing you with the condensed view for your analysis? In this way, you (a) still have the complete logs (including the actual time points at which the duplicates happen, which you will otherwise lose), (b) get the output you desire, (c) don't have to deal with all the issues of buffering/caching that have already been mentioned by others.

It’s not clear from the logs that you’ve shown that there are indeed duplicates. What makes you think 4 instances of “Squaring Number” are talking about the same number, and not actually 4 different numbers? In other words, how can you define the criteria for “duplicate messages”?

I am not sure why the approach you tried doesn't work for you. I tried exactly what you wrote in your question, and it works as intended.
However, if the problem is with the filter, you can just not use it and write the functionality yourself:
def enable_duplicate_suppression():
library_logger = logging.getLogger('library.module_name')
suppress_filter = SuppressDuplicatesFilter()
old_log = library_logger._log

def new_log(level, msg, args, exc_info=None, extra=None, stack_info=False, stacklevel=1):
    if suppress_filter.filter(msg):
        old_log(level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info, stacklevel)

library_logger._log = new_log
# Store for later removal
enable_duplicate_suppression.old_log = old_log

I trust you can figure out the rest if this even solves anything.
