# Does logger have a state in ipython?

Tags: logging, ipython

I'm running a program that creates a logger and write info message to log once. 
When I run this program as `python example.py` I get the logging message once as expected:

```
minimal.py
----------

import handout
doc = handout.Handout('output')
doc.add_text('Print this text')
```

```
λ python minimal.py
Print this text
```

When I run same program several times using IPython runfile(), the logging messages accumulate. If I run it twice, on the nex run I fill get three messages instead of one:

```
> runfile('D:/github/handout/minimal.py', wdir='D:/github/handout')
Print this text
Print this text
Print this text
```

I wonder what may cause this logger behavour in IPython? Any clues appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351287/how-to-avoid-duplicate-outputs-using-logging-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that code in question had `addHandler()` hidden in `__init__.py`. IPython alone was actually killing the handlers on shutdown, while Spyder IDE was keeping them alive, [discussion here](https://github.com/danijar/handout/issues/11)

A more quick search path for this issue could have been:

- look `addHandler` calls in your codebase (I was looking in IPython and Spyder repos)
- prevent new handler creation if there are already some:

  ```
  import logging
  import sys

  logger = logging.getLogger('handout')
  logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
  logger.propagate = False 
  if not logger.handlers:
      handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
      handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
      logger.addHandler(handler)
  ```
- remember logger is a singleton that lives on and can be accessed by its hame anywhere in the program

Workflow of logger vs handler is in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow).